# Huh ? Can't Post Image

Tags: support, images

SuperUser says that I can't post an image, and gives this reason...

[image: Can't post until reputation is greater than 10]

This shows my current level.

[image]

Huh ?  Both screen caps were taken from the same screen without reloading.

Comment: Did you try refreshing the page?

Comment: @MichaelFrank  Thanks, I am now held hostage by the captcha bot.  I can guess what the letters are (i.e., the letters in the captcha box) and I get them right after two or three tries.  At that point, the captcha bot asks me to cut and paste some random text between two boxes.  At that point, nothing happens

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue? We have a network uplink issue on this day that was likely the cause.